# Borders dissapear in Mobile Safari

Tags: iphone, css, cross-browser, responsive-design, mobile-safari

I'm starting with Twitter's Bootstrap v3. Then I add a 2px border around an iframe. See the 3rd row on [this live page](http://www.secretdesignproject.com/projects/) (NOTE: not *all* iframes on that page have the border applied).

When I shrink the window down to 300px in Chrome, the border still appears and looks normal. But when I open the same page on an iPhone, the border is cropped off on the right and bottom edge.

Is this a Safari bug? Is there a hack to fix it?

**Update**
I borrowed one-year old iPad and only the bottom border is lost.

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing iframes versus a screenshot/image wrapped in an anchor tag? Also, I don't believe this is a Safari bug, as the following example works in mobile safari: http://cdpn.io/6648ba0ca8357eb27572c54093bb35ea

Comment: @micjamking I'm using iframes because I want it to be an iframe instead of an image. Any ideas what is causing this to happen?